# ls command tells me there's no such file or directory when the file does exist?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command-line, directory

when i enter

```
cd prctcfldr
```

it tells me that i'm in the directory

```
~/prctcfldr$
```

but when i enter

```
ls prctcfldr
```

it tells me that there is no such file or directory

```
ls: cannot access 'prctcfldr': No such file or directory
```

this is happening with all my other directories including Desktop, which is really confusing since this error has not happened with my directories before, and i havent made any changes to them between now and the last time. i know the folder exists because i can see it and open it from the actual homescreen. i'm new to the linux command line and ive been looking for solutions to this error for a little while.

does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ..
```

This command moves above one directory and then you can `ls <folder name>`

Since you are already inside the folder when you `ls` again the folder name, it'll show directory does not exist.